# how to implement trait futures::stream::Stream?

Tags: rust

So I'm getting a Response from the reqwest crate and passing it to a HttpResponseBuilder from the actix_web create. However I've tried and failed to understand how to implement the Stream trait from the futures create on a custom struct to act as a middleman and copy the contents down to a file.

I've tried doing this so far, but I'm not sure what to put inside that poll_next function to make it all work.

```rust
struct FileCache {
    stream: Box<dyn futures::Stream<Item = reqwest::Result<bytes::Bytes>>>,
}

impl FileCache {
    fn new(stream: Box<dyn futures::Stream<Item = reqwest::Result<bytes::Bytes>>>) -> Self {
        FileCache { stream }
    }
}

impl Stream for FileCache {
    type Item = reqwest::Result<bytes::Bytes>;
    fn poll_next(
        self: std::pin::Pin<&mut Self>,
        cx: &mut std::task::Context<'_>,
    ) -> std::task::Poll<Option<Self::Item>> {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible but requires you to understand what [pinning](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/pin/index.html) is and how to use it safely.

Basically, we just need to proxy to `self.stream.poll_next()`, but this method accepts `Pin<&mut Self>` (as you can see in your own implementation).  Storing the box as `Pin<Box<T>>` instead of `Box<T>` will give us a way to obtain this `Pin` relatively easily, without requiring unsafe.  Making this change is straightforward, since there is a `From` implementation allowing conversion of `Box<T>` to `Pin<Box<T>>` directly:

```
use std::pin::Pin;
use std::task::{Context, Poll};
use futures::Stream;

struct FileCache {
    stream: Pin<Box<dyn Stream<Item = reqwest::Result<bytes::Bytes>>>>,
}

impl FileCache {
    fn new(stream: Box<dyn Stream<Item = reqwest::Result<bytes::Bytes>>>) -> FileCache {
        FileCache { stream: stream.into() }
    }
}
```

Now we have to figure out how to go from `Pin<&mut FileCache>` to `Pin<&mut dyn Stream<...>>`.  The correct incantation here is `self.get_mut().stream.as_mut()`:

```
impl Stream for FileCache {
    type Item = reqwest::Result<bytes::Bytes>;
    fn poll_next(self: Pin<&mut Self>, cx: &mut Context<'_>) -> Poll<Option<Self::Item>> {
        match self.get_mut().stream.as_mut().poll_next(cx) {
            Poll::Pending => Poll::Pending,
            Poll::Ready(v) => {
                // Do what you need to do with v here.
                Poll::Ready(v)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The catch is that `poll_next` isn't `async` and so you can't asynchronously wait for whatever you're doing with `v`.  `bytes::Bytes` is atomically-refcounted, though, so you could clone the inner `bytes::Bytes` value and spawn a separate task on your executor, which is probably what you want to do anyway so that whoever is waiting for `FileCache` doesn't have to wait for that task to complete before using the data.  So you'd do something like:

```
            Poll::Ready(v) => {
                if let Some(Ok(ref bytes)) = &v {
                    let bytes = bytes.clone();
                    spawn_new_task(async move {
                        // Do something with bytes
                    });
                }
                Poll::Ready(v)
            }
```

Where `spawn_new_task()` is the function your executor provides, e.g. `tokio::spawn()`.

Now that we can see what we're doing here, we can simplify this down and eliminate the `match` by pushing `Poll::Ready` into our pattern, and unconditionally returning whatever the inner `poll_next()` call did:

```
impl Stream for FileCache {
    type Item = reqwest::Result<bytes::Bytes>;
    fn poll_next(self: Pin<&mut Self>, cx: &mut Context<'_>) -> Poll<Option<Self::Item>> {
        let r = self.get_mut().stream.as_mut().poll_next(cx);
        if let Poll::Ready(Some(Ok(ref bytes))) = &r {
            let bytes = bytes.clone();
            spawn_new_task(async move {
                // Do something with bytes
            });
        }
        r
    }
}
```